# Showing an error in webview while loading the url in the view

Tags: ios

I have used as below:-

```
self.IntervalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timeaction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)






func timeaction(){

        //code for move next VC
        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

        myWebView.delegate = self

        //1. Load web site into my web view
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://eample.com")
        let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)
    }
```

But showing as error as:- Webview container loading too many times.How to fix the problem.Here i need to load the url in webview of the main view in ViewController.How to do?

Comment: you can set repeats false may it's work.

Comment: @SagarBhut    thank u ....

Comment: it's worked? for you. @clydececiljohn

Comment: @SagarBhut yes .it worked.....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. It seems that you're trying to load the web page using a timer. However, you can use the View Controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Loading the URL there will not repeatedly load it as your code currently does:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create the webview
    let myWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    view.addSubview(myWebView)

    myWebView.delegate = self

    // Load the webpage into the web view
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://eample.com")
    let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)
}
```

I want to encourage you to read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/), as this will fill you in on some general iOS knowledge that you seem to be missing. It will be more than worth it to understand these concepts if you're trying to create your own app.